# Django credit accounts example

Tags: django

Is there a Django package that handlers credits and accounts. For example, a user needs 3 credits to send an email, etc I'm looking for examples of models and functions needed for such I thing. I cannot find a package, so does anyone know of any apps in Django that do something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [django-oscar-accounts](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-accounts/blob/master/accounts/abstract_models.py) it keeps track of transactions and credit accounts. Could be adapted for you use, or you could draw ideas from the model in the link I have posted. Hope this helps.